# VBA-Copy Starting From Second Row For Each CSV

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy starting from the second row in CSVs that users are selecting.

How do I adjust the code so that:

1) Each CSV has their data pasted in the "DATA" tab but starting from row 2 for each of the CSV.

The reason for this is because there is already a header row in place.

Below is the code:

```
Sub ImportCSVsWithReference3()

    Dim xSht  As Worksheet
    Dim xSht2 As Worksheet
    Dim xWb As Workbook
    Dim xStrPath As String
    Dim xFileDialog As FileDialog
    Dim xFile As String
    Dim LstRw As Long, Rng As Range

    Set xSht2 = Sheets("DATA")

    Set xFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    xFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = True
    xFileDialog.Title = "Select a folder [CSV Consolidation]"

    If xFileDialog.Show = -1 Then
        xStrPath = xFileDialog.SelectedItems(1)
    End If

    If xStrPath = "" Then Exit Sub

    Set xSht = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    If MsgBox("Clear the existing sheet before importing?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then xSht2.UsedRange.Clear
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim vrtSelectedItem As Variant

     Set xWb = Workbooks.Open(xStrPath)
     MsgBox "Opened " & xStrPath & " for headers"

     Range("A1:R1").Copy

     'Do your work with headers here with xWb as workbook with code
     xWb.Close False

     xSht2.Activate
     Range("A1") = "File Name"
     Range("B1").Select
     ActiveSheet.Paste

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    For Each vrtSelectedItem In xFileDialog.SelectedItems

        Set xWb = Workbooks.Open(vrtSelectedItem)
        MsgBox "Opened " & vrtSelectedItem & " for content"
        'Do your work with content here with xWb as workbook with code

        Columns(1).Insert xlShiftToRight
        Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlBlanks).Value = ActiveSheet.Name
        LstRw = ActiveSheet.Range("A2" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


        ActiveSheet.LstRw.Copy xSht2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)


        xWb.Close False
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: `LstRw = ActiveSheet.Range("A2" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` maybe you meant `"A" & ...`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
i = 0
For Each vrtSelectedItem In xFileDialog.SelectedItems
    i = i + 1
    Set xWb = Workbooks.Open(vrtSelectedItem)
    Debug.Print "Opened " & vrtSelectedItem
    With xWb.Sheets(1)
        .Columns(1).Insert xlShiftToRight
        .Range("A1").Resize(.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 1).Value = .Name
        Set rngCopy = .Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        If i > 1 Then Set rngCopy = rngCopy.Offset(1, 0) 'only content if not first file
    End With
    rngCopy.Copy xSht2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    xWb.Close False
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test, please try the code below:

```
Sub ImportCSVsWithReference3()
    Dim xSht  As Worksheet
    Dim xSht2 As Worksheet
    Dim xWb As Workbook
    Dim xStrPath As String
    Dim xFileDialog As FileDialog
    Dim xFile As String
    Dim LstRw As Long, Rng As Range
    Dim vrtSelectedItem As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    Set xSht2 = Sheets("DATA")
    Set xFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    xFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = True
    xFileDialog.Title = "Select a folder [CSV Consolidation]"
If xFileDialog.Show = -1 Then
    xStrPath = xFileDialog.SelectedItems(1)
End If
If xStrPath = "" Then Exit Sub
Set xSht = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
If MsgBox("Clear the existing sheet before importing?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then xSht2.UsedRange.Clear
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set xWb = Workbooks.Open(xStrPath)
    MsgBox "Opened " & xStrPath & " for headers"
    Range("A1:R1").Copy
    xWb.Close False
    xSht2.Activate
    Range("A1") = "File Name"
    Range("B1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
For Each vrtSelectedItem In xFileDialog.SelectedItems
    i = i + 1
    Set xWb = Workbooks.Open(vrtSelectedItem)
    xWb.Sheets(1).Columns(1).Insert xlShiftToRight
    Set region = xWb.Sheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    If i > 1 Then Set region = region.Offset(1, 0)
    region.Copy xSht2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    xWb.Close False
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```